# calling test methods within other test methods

Tags: testing, unit-testing, dry

To test a method that returns a clone of the object it is called on, i need to re-run the test suite on the newly created object if i am to ensure that full functionality is retained, i found my instinct was to clone the object then call all other test methods in sequence i order to reduce code duplication. However that approach now smells to me and i can't pinpoint why. Is there a better way to test this kind of functionality?

Comment: In general, I don't try to be DRY in unit tests.  I do try to be *clear,* however.  I believe each test should stand on its own; there shouldn't be any external dependencies, other than the code under test and perhaps a mocking framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such testing might be cleaner with code contracts.  The test methods you are talking about should be invariants (must hold true before and after all public method calls) on your object, rather than unit tests.  Your clone function would have preconditions and postconditions (the postcondition would require that the object be equal to the object it cloned, and possibly that its reference was not equal).

In some cases, your code could be statically tested for compliance with such invariants.

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a requirement that should be enforced by the Clone operation